# Finding height of the tower when the angles of elevation of its top from two points are given

Tags: trigonometry

> The angle of elevation of the top of a vertical tower from a point $A$, due east of it is $45^{\circ}$. The angle of elevation of the same tower from a point $B$, due south of $A$ is $30^{\circ}$. If the distance between $A$ and $B$ is $54\sqrt2$m the find the height of the tower.

My attempt:

Let the height of tower be $h$ meters. So, the distance of the foot of the tower from $A$ is $h$ and from $B$ is $h\sqrt3$. So, $h^2+(54\sqrt2)^2=(h\sqrt3)^2\implies h=54m$.

Answer is given as $108$m.

Comment: How to write $\degree$ ?

Comment: use \circ for degree

Comment: @CSquared thanks.

Comment: @DougM is it not the other way round, the way I have written in the post? (Also, even with your approach, we are not getting the answer).

Comment: @DougM point $B$ is south of point $A$. If $C$ is the foot of the tower, so, will $CA$ and $AB$ not be perpendicular? So, $CB$ will be the hypotenuse?

Comment: Since $B$ is south of $A$, your solution is correct: $54m$.

Comment: @trancelocation thanks. Maybe you can post that as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have time right now. Hopefully someone else will do it and add a nice 3D-pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, your solution $h=54 m$ is correct.

Below is a 3d-diagram depicting the situation.

Btw., the distance from $B$ to the top of the tower is $108 m$.

[image]

Comment: What a pretty diagram!